# Count occurence of a word by ID in python

Tags: python, string, count

Following is the content of a file,My question is how to count the number of occurences for the word "optimus" for different IDs

```
    ID67    DATEUID Thank you for choosing Optimus prime. Please wait for an Optimus prime to respond. You are currently number 0 in the queue. You should be connected to an agent in approximately TIMEUID.. You are now chatting with AGENTUID   0
    ID67    Optimus MEMORYUID Hi there! Welcome to Optimus prime Web Chat. How can I help you today?        1       
    ID67    Optimus DATEUID I like to pay  prepaid from CURRENCYUID with NUMBERUID expiry on whateve date. my phone no is PHONEUID 2
    ID12120 0 0 0 is the number. They are open 0/0 so you can ring them anytime. SMILEUID   1
    ID12120 Thanks Optimus, I will give them a call. Thanks for your help! HELPUID  2
    ID5552  is the number. They are open 0/0 so you can ring them anytime. SMILEUID 1
    ID5552  Thanks Optimus, I will give them a call. Thanks for your help! HELPUID  2

for line in chat.txt:
   print line, ####print lines and count optimus word for the particular id..
```

Output should be like

```
ID67:4
ID12120
ID5552:1
```

Comment: Please let us know what approach you have selected and why it did not work as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a `defaultdict` for the counts:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
with open("chat.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        id, data = line.split(None, 1)
        d[id] += data.lower().count("optimus")
```

Comment: You should use `Counter` instead of `defaultdict` and should also not use a built in name `id` as a variable.

Comment: @Kimvais: I disagree.  You can use `Counter` it as well, but without any advantage in this particular case.

Comment: I disagree about whether there is an advantage - it is evident to _anyone_ that you will be using it for counting if it's a `Counter`, which is __not__ the case for `defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: I like more Kimvais' use of Counter.

Comment: But counter is available only after python 2.6.5 so may be a Sven Marnach is right.....

Comment: @Rajeev: In fact, this was one of the reasons I chose `defaultdict` here.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for line in chat.txt:
...     c[line.strip().split(" ",1)[0]] += line.count("Optimus")
>>> c
Counter({'ID67': 5, 'ID5552': 1, 'ID12120': 1, '': 0})
```

and you can print out the values as:

```
>>> for k, v in c.items():
...     print("{}:{}".format(k, v))
... 
:0
ID67:5
ID5552:1
ID12120:1
```

Comment: I like more Sven's coding inside the loop.