# How to count a set of strings in a file in Python?

Tags: python, readline, python-2.6

i've looked up a few threads on here but not one actually matches my situation.

I have basically a text file that looks something like this:

```
orange 0 0 0
orange 1 0 0
orange 2 0 0
orange 3 0 0
orange 4 0 0
orange 5 0 0
apple 0 0 0
apple 1 0 0
apple 2 0 0
apple 3 0 0
apple 4 0 0
apple 5 0 0
grapes 0 0 0
grapes 1 0 0
grapes 2 0 0
grapes 3 0 0
grapes 4 0 0
grapes 5 0 0
```

what I need to do, is to be able to take the first word as a string, and search how many lines contain that first word, then move on to the next word, and search for how many lines that contains that word. So the result should look something like this:

```
firstTermCount: 6
secondTermCount: 6
thirdTermCount: 6
```

I need have this count number, so that in the next step I can have a command that is supposed to run in the range of exactly how many lines of that string occurs to utilize the numbers next to each word.

the issue here is that, I have no idea what those terms are actually going to be called, so I can't do this whole "Count" or "count_dict" technique i keep seeing, since to me it seems like you need to have a set name for the function to actually look for. Plus I have no idea how many lines there will be in a file each time, I would have to do it each time I read a file. I know the example i wrote had five lines each, but honestly the type of file I want to read will have a random number of lines so I can't just say like "look for it 5 times"

Could anyone provide a solution to this issue, or perhaps a link to a thread that answers this question that I may have missed...?

Thank you

Note: I am using Python v2.6.4, if that helps

**EDIT**
So a user suggested that I use the Counter feature, or use this dictionary method, but either way it doesn't quite give me the result I need. So for example, using this Counter method (i used a work around listed [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/):

```
new list:
orange 0 0 0
orange 1 0 0
orange 2 0 0
orange 3 0 0
orange 4 0 0
apple 1 0 0
apple 2 0 0
apple 4 0 0
apple 5 0 0
grapes 1 0 0
grapes 2 0 0
grapes 4 0 0
peaches 0 0 0
peaches 1 0 0
peaches 2 0 0
peaches 3 0 0
peaches 5 0 0
peaches 6 0 0
```

and this is what the counter method gives me:

```
{'orange': 5, 'peaches': 6, 'apple': 4, 'grapes': 3}
```

when what I WANT is this:

```
{'orange': 5, 'apple': 4, 'grapes': 3,'peaches': 6 }
```

How can i get these counts in this order?

Comment: Not following your Q. Why the firstTermCount is not 6? Are you ignoring the first read? To me, it looks simple by maintaining a counter per word. What am I missing?

Comment: using `Counter` is exactly what you want here.  why do you think you'd need to know the words in advance?

Comment: Thank you, yeah I miscounted, should be 6 for this case, but that really isn't the point of my question.

And how would I use this "Counter" feature? Every thread I see (for example this one [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994195/count-occurence-of-a-word-by-id-in-python it always seems to need something to look for, but in my case I have no idea what I am looking for, I just know there will be multiple occurrences of different words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter is what you need https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lines = []
>>> with open('foo.data', 'r') as foo:
...     lines = foo.readlines()
>>> c = Counter([l.split(" ")[0] for l in lines])
>>> c
Counter({'orange': 6, 'apple': 6, 'grapes': 6})
```

Counter is new in python 2.7, so here's a "manual" solution, with order guaranteed

```
>>> manual_dict = {}
>>> with open('foo.data', 'r') as foo:
...     lines = foo.readlines()
... 
>>> for idx,l in enumerate(lines):
...     word = l.split(" ")[0]
...     if not word in manual_dict:
...         manual_dict[word] = {'count' : 0, 'pos' : 0}
...     manual_dict[word]['count'] +=1
...     if not manual_dict[word]['pos']:
...         manual_dict[word]['pos'] = idx
... 
>>> for w,w_config in sorted(manual_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['pos']):
...   print w, w_config['count']
... 
orange 5
apple 4
grapes 3
peaches 6
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really didn't think it was actually that simple.

But now something I forgot to ask is, is there now a way to take all those number counts, and put that into a list so that the result becomes [6, 6, 6]...?

Comment: c.values() will return all counter's values (like dict). You can sum them [sum(c.values())] or do what you want

Comment: okay so i just tried this and it gave me an error that Counter isn't defined. I checked what is contained in the "collections" module using the dir() command, and these are what it gives me:

`['Callable', 'Container', 'Hashable', 'ItemsView', 'Iterable', 'Iterator', 'KeysView', 'Mapping', 'MappingView', 'MutableMapping', 'MutableSequence', 'MutableSet', 'Sequence', 'Set', 'Sized', 'ValuesView', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_abcoll', '_iskeyword', '_itemgetter', '_sys', 'defaultdict', 'deque', 'namedtuple']`

What do i do...?

Comment: Counter is new in python 2.7. See my last edit without Counter

Comment: well I found this work around for the Counter thing, but either way, both your methods screws up on me on longer lists. When I tried it on a file with upto 261 lines per term, it spits out the counts in a very strange/random order going from 19, 72, 19, 19, and 41, and it's not even listed in alphabetical order. When creating a list of these counts, I need the numbers to correspond with the order of the terms listed in the file. Can that be done?

Comment: Dicts are unordered by definition. If you need to guarentee order you should use OrderedDict, but it comes with python 2.7. With python 2.6 you can install it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852800/2873381

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you want to have the words listed in the order they were found in the file, plus their counts. Dictionaries (and Counter, because its just a fancy dictionary) are unordered because their purpose is quick lookups.

The collections module has [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), along with a link to [this alternative implementation](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) if you are not using 2.7.

You could chose to implement that, or you can do something simpler by collecting the words in a list (to preserve order), and their counts:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

counts = dict()
words = list()

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       if len(line.strip()):
           bits = line.split(' ')
           if bits[0] not in words:
               words.append(bits[0])
               counts[bits[0]] = 1
           else:
               counts[bits[0]] += 1

for word in words:
    print 'Word: %s\tCount:%s' % (word, counts[word])
```